# Babel это ещу актуально или нет?

Tags: javascript, babel

Здравствуйте. Начинаю изучать JavaScript,  написал код  с использованием ECMAScript 2015. Во всех браузерах все отработало. Нужно ли сейчас использовать Babel, для превращения кода из ES6 в ES5 или это уже не актуально? Спасибо.

Comment: Как минимум, ни один IE (т.е. до 11 включительно) не понимает стрелочные функции.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Во всех браузерах все отработало

Ну не мог ты проверить во всех браузерах, сил и времени на хватит. В одном браузере один движок, в другом другой. И ни один не обязан называть какие-то вещи одинаково. Так что да, babel все еще актуален, и будет актуален долгое время, пока в один момент все браузеры не исчезнут и на их месте появятся другие с одинаковым API.

Так как для одного проканает вот это:

```
function Bla(a = 1, b = 2) {}
```

А для другого надо писать что-то вроде этого:

```
function Bla() {
  var a = arguments.length > 0 && arguments[0] !== undefined ? arguments[0] : 1;
  var b = arguments.length > 1 && arguments[1] !== undefined ? arguments[1] : 2;
}
```

Comment: Уважаемый Profesor08, большое Вам спасибо, за развернутый и понятный ответ!

Answer (score 0):

Вопросу уже полтора года, однако считаю необходимым дополнить ответ.

Чем проверять вручную в различных браузерах уже написанный код, гораздо лучше сначала сходить на [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/) или [Can I use](https://caniuse.com/), и проверить - какие браузеры поддерживают возможности и функции, которые вы собираетесь использовать. Полученные данные сравниваете с требованиями поддержки браузеров вашего проекта. И уже исходя из этого решаете - нужен ли в вашем проекте babel, и стоит ли использовать какие-то отдельно взятые "слишком новые" функции.

Comment: для того же бабеля есть `babel-env`, который делает тоже самое автоматически, подключая полифилы и транспилируя код, только если это нужно

Comment: базу данных он берет как раз из `can i use`, если не ошибаюсь